# What's the complex equation of these points in the circle?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Can there be some easy way of doing that?

I can see that there are 3 points, so the equation must be of degree 3. I can see that the radius is 2, so we have as polynomial of degree 2, I guess?

It will have this form (I believe) for this reason $$2x^3 = ..$$

but now I don't know what could be on the right hand side?

[image]

Comment: These seem to be solutions to $$z^3=-8$$

Comment: There is a strange symbol . What is it?

Comment: @Sebastiano It is an emoji which someone else has edited inside my question. It's there to express this: : /

Comment: @kathelk I thinked that it was an emoji...dont'worry.

Comment: It's intended to register (at least in my browser it does) as a yellow "smiley face" deep in thought-- placing its hand on its chin, furrowing its eyebrows and gazing upward and mouth downward in concentration. It's the ".... I wonder ...." emoji.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the circle had radius one, it would be the three roots of $x^3 = -1$. Now the radius is two, so multiplying the red dots by $\frac 1 2$ gets you to the unit circle. Hence, the three points satisfy $(\frac 1 2 x)^3 = -1$ which is equivalent to $x^3 = -8$.